# Acquia Desktop & MAMP: No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared

Tags: drush, acquia-dev-desktop

Usually I use MAMP for my local development server which already has all of my shortcuts and stuff configured the way I like it.

A client was on Acquia Cloud and to prevent conflicts with other developers we are all using the Acquia Dev Desktop for local. Acquia Dev Desktop comes with Drush within its own package.

When running my drush cc all I was getting the following error: 
No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared

After running drush status I noticed that Drush was trying to use my MAMP version of drush and thus resulting in no site found.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this answer I created a new Alias called adrush which points to the Acquia DevDesktop Version.

In my .bash_profile file in my home directory I added

alias adrush='/Applications/DevDesktop/drush/drush'

now when running drush commands for sites that are in my Acquia DevDesktop environment I enter adrush cc all